# Post complex list in Jquery Post

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I m in a situation where i need to post a complex list in my jquery post method. Here is what i m doing

```
function UpdateOrder() {
    var results = new Array();
    $("#divMainContainer").find(".teamTr").each(function() {
        var o = { 'projectid': $(this).attr("projectid"),
                  'designTeamID': $(this).attr("designTeamID"), 
                  'designTeamOrder': $(this).attr("designTeamOrder") 
                };
        results.push(o);
    });

    var url = "/DesignManagerQueue/UpdateOrder";
    $.post(url, { queryArr: results}, function(data) {
    });
```

And MVC Action is

```
public JsonResult UpdateOrder(List<SS> queryArr)
{
    //Do something
    return Json(new { Status = true, Message = "" });
}
```

And Class is

```
public class SS
{
    public string Projectid{ get; set; }
    public int DesignTeamID{ get; set; }
    public int DesignTeamOrder { get; set; }
}
```

But in action

```
List<SS> queryArr
```

is empty

Any Ideas?

Comment: which MVC are you using? and which language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model binding in the ASP.NET MVC framework is simple. Your action methods need data, and the incoming HTTP request carries the data you need. The catch is that the data is embedded into POST-ed form values, and possibly the URL itself.  [Model Binding in MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410405%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Model binding expects your properties should match the the model class.

```
 var o = { 'ProjectId': $(this).attr("projectid"),
                  'DesignTeamID': $(this).attr("designTeamID"), 
                  'DesignTeamOrder': $(this).attr("designTeamOrder") 
                };
```

Comment: In my question , properties are not same, are they case sensitive?

Answer (score 0):

your js object properties should match those of your model class

```
public class SS
{
    public string Projectid{ get; set; }
    public int DesignTeamID{ get; set; }
    public int DesignTeamOrder { get; set; }
}
```

like

```
  var o = { 'ProjectId': $(this).attr("projectid"),
                  'DesignTeamID': $(this).attr("designTeamID"), 
                  'DesignTeamOrder': $(this).attr("designTeamOrder") 
                };
```